# How can I link OpenLDAP with multiple AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, directoryservices, ldap-query

I am working on a solution in which we are securing Hadoop echo system and its components.
My use case is I want to Authenticate the user from its AD and these ADs can be multiple. in short, this is a multi-tenant solution and each tenant or customer have their own AD so how can I link OpenLDAP with multiple AD

NOTE: There is no trust relationship needed between the ADs. means a user must authenticate from its own AD not any other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've considered the possible security implications of doing this (i.e. ensure CustomerA cannot adversely impact CustomerB) as well as potential customer unease (I've had to maintain completely separate servers to house different customer directories because clients were uneasy about having the service running *their* partition on the same machine running some other customer's directory service) ... [Referrals](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/referrals.html) should be able to do this -- different OUs in OpenLDAP would refer out to the various AD environments. You may need to configure an option within your application to *follow* referrals.